# replacing application icon after build

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to brand a specific white labeled app and it needs to get the appropriate app icon, so that when I browse to the exe in file explorer it shows with the branded icon. I dont mean changing the icon at runtime because that is not a problem.

I have tried accessing the assemblies with mono.cecil and replacing the resource called "app.ico" but it doesnt seem to work. I also tried to use pack URIs in xaml but that doesnt work because at compile time I dont know where the branding resources are located.

I know that this can possibly be done during a pre-build event but I prefer replacing the icon after the exe is built.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In the 'Solution Explorer' in Visual Studio, select the startup project. Either right click on it and select 'Properties', or just press Alt+Enter on the keyboard to open the project properties. On the 'Application' tab, you should see a 'Resources' section. Click on the 'Icon and manifest' and select an icon for your application. Is that what you were talking about?